# How to properly define the routes of my rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am following [this tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#top) and at first the `config/routes.rb` file contained these:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

  get "pages/home"

  get "pages/contact"

  get "pages/about"

  get "pages/help" 

...
```

now in the tutorial it states that it contains these

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
  match '/about',   :to => 'pages#about'
  match '/help',    :to => 'pages#help'
  .
  .
  .
end
```

I used the above, but it doesn't seem to work. what is the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

Both match and get are valid route definitions. I would recommand using get though.

```
get "/home" => "pages#home"
```

This will route the uri /home to the controller Pages, with the action home.
But only for the GET requests.

You could do, for example :

```
post "/home" => "pages#create_home"
```

If you use match :

```
match "/home" => "pages#home"
```

This will route the uri /home to the controller Pages, with the action home. But for **all** HTTP verbs, not only GET.

Take a look at the rails guides : [routing applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct and valid. Read through [this guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints) for more info. Maybe, you're trying to access `'/pages/contact'` which doesn't work any more and you have to access that page by just `'/contact'`.